# How can i fetch current url form CustomTabs in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am working on react-native app . I am using CustomTabs to open external URL. Its working properly but I want to fetch current URL from CustomTabs into my react-native app and want to close CutomTabs automatically. the URL 'https://www.demo.com' have forms and after submission redirecting to the another page with some parameters included into the URL. I want to fetch that parameters into my app .
my Code is:-

```
url = 'https://www.demo.com';
CustomTabs.openURL(url,{ toolbarColor: '#607D8B',enableUrlBarHiding: true,showPageTitle: true,enableDefaultShare: true,animations: ANIMATIONS_SLIDE}).then((launched: boolean) => {

console.log(`Launched custom tabs: ${launched}`);
}).catch(err => {
console.error(err)
```

How can i do this ??

});

Comment: is it possible with CustomTabs ?

Comment: From my surfing knowledge, due to user privacy control we can't able to get the url from custom tabs.